# Nginx and auth_basic with cgit

Tags: nginx, cgit

On an Arch Linux server running Nginx, I setup correctly cgit. I want to protect cgit with a basic authentication password, except for one directory `/pub/`. As seen on [the documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule#auth_basic), I thought about put on the `server` context an authentication, and get an exception with the `location` context for the `/pub/` directory. I tried [this link](http://nginxlibrary.com/password-protect-a-directory/) to get the path correctly.

Here the configuration file of nginx of the corresponding part.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  git.nicosphere.net;
    index cgit.cgi;
    gzip off;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/gitosis/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/webapps/cgit/;
    }

    location ^~ /pub/  {
        auth_basic off;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^/([^?/]+/[^?]*)?(?:\?(.*))?$ /cgit.cgi?url=$1&$2 last;
    }

    location ~ \.cgi$ {
        gzip off;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index   cgit.cgi;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/webapps/cgit/cgit.cgi;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/share/webapps/cgit/;
    }
}
```

This ask me for authentication for whatever any url are. For some easier tests, I tried to leave root without authentication, and only `/pub/` with authentication. In this case, it doesn't ask for password at all. So far, I managed to protect either everything or nothing.

Thanks for your help, and my apologies for my approximative English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  git.nicosphere.net;
    index cgit.cgi;
    gzip off;

    root /usr/share/webapps/cgit;

    # $document_root is now set properly, and you don't need to override it
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/cgit.cgi;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @cgit;
    }

    # Require auth for requests sent to cgit that originated in location /    
    location @cgit {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /srv/gitosis/.htpasswd;

        gzip off;
        # rewrites in nginx don't match the query string
        rewrite ^/([^/]+/.*)?$ /cgit.cgi?url=$1 break;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
    }

    location ^~ /pub/  {
        gzip off;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+/.*)?$ /cgit.cgi?url=$1 break;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,

This is better, but there is a strange behavior, when I go to `/pub/`, it ask me for a password, and when I press 'cancel', it shows the page (without CSS and .PNG). When I try the root, it does show the 401 unauthorized page. If I authenticate correctly, everything is fine (with CSS/PNG).

So, I guess I still have a problem, but it's better.